# Example of Mvx.MvxBindableListView

Tags: mvvmcross

Does anyone have a complete sample source code for `Mvx.MvxBindableListView`?
I have tried so many times, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross is an open-sourced framework, you can find all of its source code on Github. Here's the control that you specifically asked about from vNext (which is 1 version behind, v3 is the latest):
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxBindableListView.cs

In MvvmCross v3 MvxBinableListView is called MvxListView
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs